# Flutter socket_io_client firing multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

I am using socket_io_client for my flutter project. It is working fine but each time I go back and again to the widget, socket connection fires up again and it prints n+1 number of times. The same with disconnect. How do I resolve this?

```
IO.Socket socket;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createSocketConnection();
  }
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    socket.disconnect();
  }
  createSocketConnection() {
    socket = IO.io("url", <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': false
    });
    socket.on("connect", (data) {
      print("connected");
      socket.emit("join", groupId);
    });
    socket.on("newMessage", (data) {
      print(data);
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", (_) {
      print("disconnected");
    });
    socket.on("close", (_) {
      print("closed");
    });
    socket.connect();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it happens cuz you initiated the createSocketConnection();
in initieState you should use one of the state management architectures i suggest you to use bloc library here is the link [bloc library](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture) i hope it will help you.